# What is the gradient in circle animation in ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, animation, gradient, progressdialog

What is the gradient in circle animation in ProgressDialog?

I would like to use it on my own and I really like its colors... could you help me out a bit?

Comment: Varies based on the version. Below 2.3, I think it's a white->grey, in 2.3, a grey->white, in 3.0-3.2, a blue->transparent, and in 4.0, a white->transparent. Which version did you mean?

Comment: That's it :) I meant the one above 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Honeycomb (as per comments) `ProgressDialog` animation, there are two alternating colors. One, I believe, is `#72a6de`, and the second, `#5380c4`. Each of the color rings fades from that main color into transparency (0 alpha).

Note that you can look at the [Honeycomb UI designs](https://www.google.ca/search?um=1&hl=en&biw=1745&bih=868&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=honeycomb+ui&oq=honeycomb+ui&aq=f&aqi=g1g-S1g-mS3&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24j0i5i24l3.288565.288606.0.288792.2.2.0.0.0.0.166.243.1j1.2.0...0.0.RaAGWUPeKcE) to and use an eyedropper (Photoshop, GIMP, or even Paint) to pick and choose your colors.

Lastly, I will show you [this link in the Android developer pages](http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html) where they list best practices for colors to use. This includes the contemporary blue, the old-fashioned green, and the best complements for them.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for nice answer :) Good luck to you too!